# DAX - TOPN() in a SUMX() for multiple transactions

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculated-columns

I need your help.

I am trying to make a calculated column which sum the sales for the last two dates (there are not sales on all dates!) for each product.

I have tried to use the calculation:

```
CALCULATE (
    SUMX ( TOPN ( 2; 'Table'; 'Table'[date_ID] ); 'Table'[Sale] );
    ALLEXCEPT ( Table; 'Table'[Product_ID] )
)
```

But this only works if you have one sale per date per product ID.

What do I do if there are many transactions per date and prod ID?

Below I have a table where I have (filtered) one date and one product.

[image]

Now, I have made a calculated column that sums all transactions per date and product ID (for reference). 
This is

```
Calculated Column 2 =
CALCULATE (
    SUMX ( Table; Table[Sale] );
    ALLEXCEPT ( Table; 'Table'[Date]; 'Table'[Product_ID] )
)
```

[image]

Now comes the difficult part.
If I want to sum the transactions for the last two dates on each product, I have made the following calculation:

```
Calculated Column 1 =
VAR SumProd =
    CALCULATE (
        SUMX ( Table; Table[Sale] );
        ALLEXCEPT ( Table; Table[Date]; Table[Product_ID] )
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUMX ( TOPN ( 2; 'Table'; 'Table'[Date] ); SumProd );
        ALLEXCEPT ( Table; Table[Product_ID]; Table[Date] )
    )
```

[image]

The Problems:

1. The calculations sums ALL the values in each category

Example: in the table, you see `"Calculated column 1"=7571200`, which is 27040 * number of transactions? I only want the value 27040.

2. For some reason, the TOPN() doesn’t work. If I change the `N_Value=2` to `N_Value=3`, the calculation doesn’t change?

Please, does anyone know what is wrong with my calculation?

Thanks.

Br,
Jakob

Answer (score 0):

In your measure, `SumProd` is a constant that you're summing for each row in the table. This is not what you want.

I'd suggest something more like this:

```
Calculated Column 1 =
VAR LastTwoDates =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        VALUES ( Table[Date] );
        TOPN ( 2; ALLEXCEPT ( Table; Table[Product_ID] ); Table[Date] )
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Table[Sale] );
        ALLEXCEPT ( Table; Table[Product_ID] );
        Table[Date] IN LastTwoDates
    )
```

In this, we first calculate a list of the top 2 dates associated with `Product_ID` and store it as a variable. Then we use that as a filter when calculating the sum of `Sale`.

---

I'm not positive this exact syntax will work, but I hope it will point you in a better direction.

---

It turns out my code didn't work exactly as intended. Try this instead:

```
Calculated Column 1 =
VAR ProductDates =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        VALUES ( Table1[Date] );
        ALLEXCEPT ( Table1; Table1[Product_ID] )
    )
VAR LastTwoDates = TOPN ( 2; ProductDates; [Date] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Table1[Sale] );
        ALLEXCEPT ( Table1; Table1[Product_ID] );
        Table1[Date] IN LastTwoDates
    )
```

Comment: Thanks Alexis, It looks great, but I keep getting this error for the Variable, and I can't figure out where it goes wrong:  "The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value".

Comment: It looks like it wants a value rather than a column in the 3rd `TOPN` argument. Please try my edit.

Comment: Alexis! Thanks a lot. It works exactly as I want it. Your solution is greatly appreciated. Have a nice weekend.